# passing 'const' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, vector, virtual

I have this:

```
// Get the Application Constructor Vector
vector<ApplicationConstructor> Application::getAppConstructorVector(){
   return this->AppConstructorVector;
}
```

here Application is an abstract class with an abstract method called `ShowData()`:

```
 void DesktopApplication::ShowData() const{
 cout << "-------------------------AppConstructor Details----------------------------------------------" << endl;
 vector<ApplicationConstructor> appConstructorVector = this->getAppConstructorVector();
 for (int i= 0; i < appConstructorVector.size(); i ++)
 {
     cout << "Contructor Code: " << appConstructorVector.at(i).getConstructorCode()
          << "Name: " << appConstructorVector.at(i).getConstructorName() 
          << "Email: " << appConstructorVector.at(i).getConstructorEmail()
          << endl;
 }     
}
```

where `desktopApplication` extends Application and implements the abstract Method `Showdata()`

I have this:

```
void AppSystem::ShowData(const Application &app){
   app.ShowData();
}
```

where AppSystem is a class which has a property of  `vector<Application *> &ApplicationVector;`
and in main I have this

```
  GameApplication app1(true, "Puzzle", (char *)"game1456", "Tetris", "1.0.0", appConstructor1, 10.0); 
  GameApplication *appPtr1 = &app1;
  AppSystem appSystem;
  appSystem.PushAppToApplicationVector(appPtr1);
  appSystem.ShowData(*appPtr1);
```

I get this :

> error: passing 'const DesktopApplication' as 'this' argument discards
>   qualifiers [-fpermissive] although I call the GameApplication
>   showData() not the DesktopApplication one. Any suggestion?

Comment: -> `std::vector<ApplicationConstructor> Application::getAppConstructorVector() const` and even `const std::vector<ApplicationConstructor>& Application::getAppConstructorVector() const`

Comment: *"`(char *)"game1456"`"* :-( fix your constructor instead of that cast.

Comment: Why is that? I can't access this object inside a const method?

Comment: You cannot call non-const method (on `this`) inside const method.

Comment: I have an enumerator inside Application class and a getEnumerator() Method which returns it.Now in DesktopApplication I want to switch() the getEnumerator() return value.How can I do it?